# dynamic images list using php mysql smarty inside jquery

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I want to print list of image address in jquery function using php(adodb) and smarty.

i need to this :

```
 $.lightbox(["/media/photos/tmb/4.jpg", "/media/photos/tmb/3.jpg", "/media/photos/tmb/6.jpg"]);
```

i try with this (just simple for test) :

```
 {/literal} {if $photos} $.lightbox(["{"\", \""|implode:$photos}"]); {/if}{literal}
```

result is :

```
 $.lightbox(["Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array"]);
```

Actually, i need to replace array with  images address.

images address (dynamic loop) :

```
{$relative}/media/photos/tmb/{$photos[i].PID}.jpg
```

without jquery function, i list images with this methods :

```
{if $photos}
{section name=i loop=$photos}
{$relative}/media/photos/tmb/{$photos[i].PID}.jpg
{/section}
{/if}
```

php code:

```
    $sql            = "SELECT PID, caption FROM photos WHERE AID = " .$aid. " AND status = '1' LIMIT " .$limit;
    $rs             = $conn->execute($sql);
    $photos         = $rs->getrows();
    $smarty->assign('photos', $photos);
```

how to print list for my need? can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is assign the array to your template, and use `json_encode()`.  I don't use Smarty very often, but I believe you can just do:

```
{$yourImageArray | json_encode}
```

---

**Edit:** Now that you've finally told us  what your array contains:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 13 [PID] => 13 [1] => [caption] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 14 [PID] => 14 [1] => [caption] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 15 [PID] => 15 [1] => [caption] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 30 [PID] => 30 [1] => salam [caption] => salam ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 17 [PID] => 17 [1] => [caption] => ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 31 [PID] => 31 [1] => [caption] => ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 32 [PID] => 32 [1] => [caption] => ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 33 [PID] => 33 [1] => [caption] => ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 34 [PID] => 34 [1] => [caption] => ))

Here's what you need to do.  In your controller:

```
$photoFileNames = array();
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $photoFileNames[] = $photo['PID'];
}

$smarty->assign('photoFileNamesJSON', json_encode($photoFileNames));
```

In your template, you can access the array via `$photoFileNamesJSON`.  The next time you post a question, please include all of the information from the start.  It will be much easier to provide a more specific answer, if you are specific with your question.

Comment: @BBKing, You're trying to turn a PHP array into a JavaScript array, yes?  The easiest way to do this is convert it to JSON, which is directly compatible with JavaScript.  If in PHP you do this: `json_encode(array(1, 2, 3, 4))`, you will get `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.  In Smarty, you can pipe data through any PHP function, so if you follow my example in my answer, you should get that array converted to JavaScript, ready to go inside some JS code.

Comment: +1. Can you help Me With complete code ? many thanks for help

Comment: @BBKing, Have you tried pasting that line in above, and plugging in the variable of your array to see what happens?  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: i understand your mean. but i dont have any idea for php(adodb) and generate json array for smarty.

Comment: Put this on your smarty page:  `{$photos | json_encode}`  What is the output?

Comment: @BBKing, In your controller, do a `die(print_r($photos, true))` instead of your smarty assign.  What do you see?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 13 [PID] => 13 [1] => [caption] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 14 [PID] => 14 [1] => [caption] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 15 [PID] => 15 [1] => [caption] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 30 [PID] => 30 [1] => salam [caption] => salam ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 17 [PID] => 17 [1] => [caption] => ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 31 [PID] => 31 [1] => [caption] => ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 32 [PID] => 32 [1] => [caption] => ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 33 [PID] => 33 [1] => [caption] => ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 34 [PID] => 34 [1] => [caption] => ))

Comment: @BBKing, And where do you expect to get your image file name?  From the PID?

Comment: Sure!from the PID. This Complete Address : `/media/photos/tmb/{PID}.jpg` example :`/media/photos/tmb/13.jpg` `/media/photos/tmb/14.jpg` `/media/photos/tmb/15.jpg`

Comment: I see This. Not Worked . I put your code in my controller and this `{$photoFileNamesJSON | json_encode}` in smarty. i just see last `PID` in result: `"34"`

Comment: this worked now. many thanks. i see little problem. i change this line for full path image address : `$photoFileNames[] = $photo['PID'];` to `$photoFileNames[] = '/media/photo/'.$photo['PID'].'.jpg';` now i see in result : `["\/media\/photo\/13.jpg","\/media\/photo\/14.jpg","\/media\/photo\/15.jpg","\/media\/photo\/30.jpg","\/media\/photo\/17.jpg","\/media\/photo\/31.jpg","\/media\/photo\/32.jpg","\/media\/photo\/33.jpg","\/media\/photo\/34.jpg","\/media\/photo\/35.jpg","\/media\/photo\/36.jpg"]` how to fix this ?

Comment: fixed this using ` json_encode($images,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` thanks for any help to me brad. god bless you.